# Getting only one record in the response using ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a small part of the code. I have to get the data using ajax but I am getting only one field.

There is no issue with the value and I am getting the correct one. I have to send the result to ajax but I am getting only one field.

I believe there is some issue with my array.

```
$result=[];

      if ($haschange['fb']==1) {
       $result[]="<input type='text' value='".$social_links['fb']."'>";
      }
      if ($haschange['twitter']==1) {
        $result[]="<input type='text' value='".$social_links['twitter']."'>";
      }
       if ($haschange['linkedin']==1) {
         $result[]="<input type='text' value='".$social_links['linkedin']."'>";
      }
       if ($haschange['instagram']==1) {
         $result[]="<input type='text' value='".$social_links['instagram']."'>";
       
      }
    

echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.pendingContent', function(){  
  
      var id=$(this).data("id");
     //alert(id);
      $.ajax({
              url: 'process.php',
              method:'post',
              dataType: "json", 
              data:{action:"pendingContent",id:id},  
              success: function(data){
                $('#shaedcontent').html(data);
                $("#pendingContent").modal('show');
              }
            });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the posted PHP is `process.php`? Where does `$haschange` come from? How is it populated? There is some part missing here. Please post _all_ relevant code and explain the relationship between the data you pass in (the id) and the response.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Yes, it's the process.php page and as of now I am getting the FB and Twitter condition true but it's displaying only FB on page

Comment: At the moment, the question is unanswerable since we're missing a very important part in the flow.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, ok. is my code is the correct way to send the data to ajax? like the result I am sending

Comment: Sure, but that should be easy to test on your own, just hard code a few inputs and see how it works. However, `$('#shaedcontent').html(data)` will set the _json array_ as the content to that element (you're returning a json array, not pure HTML)

Comment: It will give you array back ..So , just loop through that array and append them inside you dom .

Comment: Thanks for the help. what I did, i removed the array and added dot(.) like this $result.

Comment: Then you can remove `dataType: "json",` and `json_encode()` since you're just returning the HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Yes, you are right. Removed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your and other comments basically already described it. If we assume that `$haschange` has different values, your array should be okay. If you are not sure, just check the return of that function inside your browser within the developer tools.

As we should have an array posted to the ajax function, you should have an array. Your access on the array is not correct as you just add the array (json string) to the html element.

The best approach is to use a foreach loop to go through each object within the json response. If you are not sure what you have received in the ajax method, just use `console.log(data)`. With this you should see a proper json object.